# Which came first: いや (the interjection), or 嫌がる and similar words?

Tags: etymology

I assume that the interjection いや is cognate with a bunch of other words beginning with *iya-* such as 嫌がる、卑しい, perhaps via the semantics of 'disagreeable'.

But did the interjection come first and get lexicalised into verbs and adjectives? Or does the interjection *derive* from the other forms? Which is the earlier form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the entry of いや in 日本国語大辞典:

> 否定の感動詞「いな」が中世に「いや」になったと見られる。肯定否定の対応としては、狂言などでは「無いか？」「いや、ござらぬ」のように、否定的な疑問に対して、後続語句に対応した使い方をすることが多かった。

The interjection sense first appears in 1254:

> ＊古今著聞集〔１２５４〕一六・五二九「『〈略〉件（くだんの）田は相違あるまじ』などいへば、権守とりもあへず『いや田におきては、はやくとられぬ』といひたりけるをかしさこそ」

And the adjective in 1477:

> ＊史記抄〔１４７７〕八・孝景本紀「先帝の人をわづらはす事をいやにをぼしめしたほどにとてか」

It suggests that the adjective usage of いや (with all its derivation) is a secondary development.

While いや derives from an older form いな in the middle ages, いやしい dates back to 日本書紀, that means those two are not cognate.

> ＊日本書紀〔７２０〕景行二七年一二月（北野本訓）「是を以て、賤（イヤシキ）賊（あた）の陋（いや）しき口を以て尊号（みな）を奉らむ」

As an aside, いな also generated a derived verb, namely いなぶ > [いなむ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%90%A6%E3%82%80_%28%E3%81%84%E3%81%AA%E3%82%80%29/) "deny, negate", which has been widely used till now.